# Priority Queues Using Total Order Relation

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am trying to use priority queues. My priority queues class consist of an interface entry class and now I need to make a comparator class which I can use later on with my abstractPriorityQueue class. Although I need to use total ordering relation and I am having trouble understanding how to implement it in java. This is what I have so far.

```
public class CompareKeys implements Comparator<K> 
   {
      public int compare(K k1, k k2) 
      {
         if (k1 <= k2 || k2 <= k1)
            k1 = k2;
      }
   }
```

In addition, if i said "public class CompareKeys implements Comparator", does that mean it is no longer a total ordering relation?

Comment: What do ypu mean by _tptal ordering_?  You cannot compare any object using relational operator `<=`; also method `compare` must return an `int` value

Comment: Classes usually `implements Comparable` not `Comparator`.

Comment: I am trying to implement this code in a total ordering relation. ```public class DefaultComparator<E> implements Comparator<E> { 
public int compare(E a, E b) throws ClassCastException 
{
return ((Comparable<E>) a).compareTo(b); 
}}``` 
In my textbook it says that total ordering satisfies the following properties for any keys k1, k2, and k3: Comparability property: k1 ≤ k2 or k2 ≤ k1. Antisymmetric property: if k1 ≤ k2 and k2 ≤ k1, then k1 = k2. • Transitive property: if k1 ≤ k2 and k2 ≤ k3, then k1 ≤ k3.

Answer (score 0):

You should review existing static methods in [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) to create `Comparator` instances:

- `static <T,​U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<? super T,​? extends U> keyExtractor)` -- compare objects of class `T` by the `keyExtractor` - a function which returns a "key" implementing interface `Comparable` -- usually it is a reference to getter method.

Compare objects by fields having primitive types `double`, `int`, or `long`

- `static <T> Comparator<T> comparingDouble​(ToDoubleFunction<? super T> keyExtractor)`
- `static <T> Comparator<T> comparingInt​(ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor)`
- `static <T> Comparator<T> comparingLong​(ToLongFunction<? super T> keyExtractor)`

For example, class `Foo` has fields `String bar` and `int baz` with appropriate getters, so the following comparators may be created:

```java
Comparator<Foo> byBar = Comparator.comparing(Foo::getBar);
Comparator<Foo> byBaz = Comparator.comparingInt(Foo::getBaz);
```

Comparators may be joined using [`Comparator.thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.Comparator)):

```java
Comparator<Foo> byBarAndBaz = byBar.thenComparing(byBaz);
```